# Verifying Client with Server

Tags: java, authentication, client, server, md5sum

I'm currently designing a basic Java program that uses sockets to communicate from a server to multiple clients. I want the clients to be unmodified, however, to prevent against users trying to use the software not how it was intended. I'm considering using an MD5 checksum and sending it to the server to compare it with what the checksum *should* be, but a modified client could simply send an incorrect checksum to fake the server into thinking that the client is untouched.

To put it simply, how would I go about verifying a client in such a way, that a modified client cannot fake being unmodified?

(Note: This is a question cross-posted from [security stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/93534/verifying-client-with-server), due to a suggestion to post it here)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very big question, and the short answer is that you can't guarantee that the client code is not modified, especially not in a "basic" program.

Your server shouldn't rely on treating the client as trusted but instead handle all access control, validation and such on its end.

A way that you could slow down or deter the people who may want to modify the code would be to require both the hash you described and a signature which would make it much more annoying to do- but no, unfortunately, you cannot verify that the client is definitely 100% unmodified.

Comment: By signature, do you mean the file signature? As this is designed in Java, the file signature / magic number will always be CA FE BA BE. If you're talking about a different type of signature, what is it?